# Avoiding Mocks When Generating Response Data in Elixir

Tags: testing, mocking, elixir

I've come to understand that mocks are not generally well thought of in the Elixir community. With that in mind, I have the following predicament I'm not quite sure how to solve.

First, my current design using https://github.com/jjh42/mock

```
remote_api_generated_data = %{
  transaction_id: "09200-12-235089721-3987235",
  confirmation_number: "JB789FKS78GS82"
}

with_mock RemoteApi.Client, [order: Mocks.RemoteApi.Client.successful_transaction(&1, vaulted_data)] do
  conn = post conn, transaction_path(conn, :create), data: [@create_attrs]
  response = json_response(conn, 201)["data"]
  assert response.composite_key == "#{remote_api_generated_data.transaction_id}:#{remote_api_generated_data.confirmation_number}"
end
```

---

José Valim offers a nice mocking solution using protocols and configuration files. See the post for details: http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2015/10/mocks-and-explicit-contracts

My question is this: **How can you take the approach of "protocols and configuration changes" and still validate on remotely generate data?** (Recognizing that it's not the data itself, but the transformation of it that I'm asserting. In this case the `composite_key`)

Answer (score 1):

The approach I find useful is to use a tool like [ex_vcr](https://github.com/parroty/exvcr) at the boundary of the system, and only for the purpose of ensuring that remote data can be deserialized into well defined structs.

This acts like an integration test that will use a cached response from the remote system.

All the application business logic and data transformations can be defined as plain old elixir modules and functions which can be tested directly.